# Flutter web project not allowed by CORS policy

Tags: flutter, cors

I am new creating Flutter web projects, and I have found the first issue when trying to make http connections to files hosted on the same server where the Flutter web build is deployed.

This is the code:

```
 Future<User> obtenerUsuario() async {

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    var url = "https://.../login.php";
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "email": controlUsuario.text,
      "password": controlContrasena.text
    });

    print("respuesta :"+response.body);
```

And this is the error message from browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.../login.php' from origin 'http://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The project is hosted on a AWS Ubuntu instance.

Comment: What technology are you using on the backend? CORS is something that you need to enable from the backend side.

Comment: @RoniAntonio, PHP files as web services and API.

Comment: We have actually had similar issues. It seems Flutter is demanding CORS, even though the server really doesn't need or want it. Why should Flutter demand it in the first place?
We now had to make a proxy that enables CORS and then removes all restrictions "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your server `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```